# fncychap: Remove vertical space between heading and first element in toF and toT

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, fncychap

I'm trying to remove the vertical spacing that occurs when using the fncychap package, but how to do this? I've already done it in the toc by writing the following:

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-70pt}
```

The last line is the one that moves things back to place in `toc`. Is there a similar way to do this in `lof` and `lot`?

[image]

Comment: `fncychap` is hated by many people. Please save them some time by providing a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `fncychap`. All those styles can be generated easily by `titlesec`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\filleft\bfseries}
{\titlerule[1pt]%
\vspace{1ex}%
\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
{20pt}
{\Huge}[\vspace{1ex}{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\filleft\bfseries}
{}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[1pt]
\vspace{1ex}%
\Huge}[\vspace{1ex}{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{20pt}   %% adjust these numbers
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless} {0pt}{20pt}{20pt}   %% adjust these numbers

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I will not accept this for solving my problem, as it don't. I asked how to do it while using fncychap. :)

Comment: @NicolaiAntonLynnerup You are welcome `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

I will have to admit that I now agree with @HarishKumar. The solution to my problem was to skip the fncychap package and use titlesec instead.

Here's the code I've generated from @HarishKumar's example.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filleft}
{\sc\chaptertitlename\ \Huge{\thechapter}\\%
\vspace{1.5cm}
\titlerule[1pt]}
{-20pt}
{\Large}[\vspace{2ex}{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filleft}
{}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[1pt]
\vspace{2ex}%
\Large}[\vspace{2ex}{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}   %% adjust these numbers
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless} {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}   %% adjust these numbers
```